# gitlab ci: Pass artifacts from two jobs of the same stage

Tags: devops, gitlab-ci, pipeline

Having some multiple jobs (not in parallel) and I'm trying to pass artifacts from the first job to the second one.

Here what it's look like:

```
    deploy-build-docker 1/2:
      stage: deploy
      image: docker:stable
      script:
      - ...
      artifacts:
        paths:
        - path

    deploy-preprod 2/2:
      stage: deploy
      image: alpine
      dependencies: [deploy-build-docker]
      script:
      -  ....
```

CI can't find dependencies, and give me this error `deploy-preprod 2/2 job: undefined dependency: deploy-build-docker`

I also tried `deploy`, `deploy-build-docker 1/2` but I still have the same issue.

So how can i do that? Should I must do the build in another stage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can only pass artifacts from **previous** stages.

> By default, all artifacts from all previous stages are passed, but you can use the dependencies parameter to define a limited list of jobs (or no jobs) to fetch artifacts from.
>
> To use this feature, define dependencies in context of the job and pass a list of all previous jobs from which the artifacts should be downloaded. You can only define jobs from stages that are executed before the current one. An error will be shown if you define jobs from the current stage or next ones.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dependencies

Although they might add support for `needs:` in future to reference jobs in the **current** stage: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/30632